# system of diffrential eqation in python

Tags: python, differential-equations

How can I solve 31 coupled equations in Python?
I solve 4 coupled with solve_ivp
but I can't solve 32.

````
   wp=0.6    # field frequency
   g=0.6    # coupling strength 
   n_p = 1     # number of photons
   C = np.sqrt(n_p+1)    
   dydx_0= 0
   dydx_1= 0
   dydx_2= -C*y[5]-wp*y[3]
   dydx_3= -C*y[4]-wp*y[2] 
   .
   .
   .
   dydx_28= -C*y[27]+wp*y[29]
   dydx_29= +C*y[26]-wp*y[28]
   dydx_30=  0
   dydx_31=  0```
````

Comment: Is there any systematic behind these equations? By the general form it looks like this, but the signs are not in favor. Is this the discretization of some PDE? (Also note that from 0 to 31 there are 32 numbers.)

Comment: It is made of a matrix that I separated

Comment: What would, for instance, the equations 10 and 11 look like, and where does the pattern change?